# Adaptive metropolis within Gibbs

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, gibbs

I once saw some study claims to use the algorithm referred to as "Adaptive Metropolis within Gibbs". Are there any formal introduction on this algorithm? What are the difference between this algorithm with pure MH algorithm and Gibbs sampler?

Comment: Are you asking about "adaptive" ([Andrieu & Thoms, 2008](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/sail/readings/andrieu-thoms.pdf)]) or about "Metropolis-within-Gibbs" (see [an earlier answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/184413/7224))?

Comment: @Xi'an, thanks a lot!